# json-schema repeated code

Tags: swagger, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

This pattern appears repeatedly (six times) in my project:

```
        type: object
          properties:
            total:
              type: integer
              description: the count of all items that match the query
            hits:
              type: array
              description: a single page of results
              items:
                $ref: '#/definitions/{various schema}'
```

The inner part of this repeated pattern (`{various schema}`)  varies on each use. I'd like to reference shared code for each of these rather than repeating myself. I'd usually use `$ref`, but that doesn't seem to work here because of the variable bit.

I've tried to make `anyOf` work for me, but it only helps vary `properties` of an `object`, but I'm trying to vary `items` of an `array`.

Is there something I'm missing? Possibly a minor refactor to make this fit into a reusable pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define your repeated pattern, except the `items` constraint, and then use `allOf` in each variation.

Your reusable schema would be this way:

```
  reusable:
    type: object
      properties:
        total:
          type: integer
          description: the count of all items that match the query
        hits:
          type: array
          description: a single page of results
```

When you want to define a variation, you make use of `allOf` adding the reusable schema and the additional constraint:

```
variation1:
  allOf:
    - reusable
    - properties:
        hits:
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/variation_schema'
```

Comment: That brings my ten lines down to six, still repeated six times. Not what I had hoped for, but still better than anything I thought of. Thanks!